# Using pre-trained transformer with keras

Tags: nlp, text-classification, bert-language-model

I want to use this pre-trained model: [Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic](https://huggingface.co/Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic)

I use this code to build model using Keras (the library I generally use):

```py
def build_model(transformer, max_len=512):
    """
    function for training the model
    """
    input_word_ids = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    sequence_output = transformer(input_word_ids)[0]
    cls_token = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
    out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(cls_token)
        
    model = Model(inputs=input_word_ids, outputs=out)
    model.compile(Adam(lr=3e-5), loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
    # changed from 1e-5 to 3e-5
    return model

with strategy.scope():
    model_name = "Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic"
    transformer_layer = (
        transformers.AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    )
    model = build_model(transformer_layer, max_len=MAX_LEN)
```

The following error happens:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-26bbcd63ea51> in <module>()
      5         # .TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-large')
      6     )
----> 7     model = build_model(transformer_layer, max_len=MAX_LEN)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    922             raise ValueError("You cannot specify both input_ids and inputs_embeds at the same time")
    923         elif input_ids is not None:
--> 924             input_shape = input_ids.size()
    925             batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    926         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Are you trying to fine tune a Bert model ?

Comment: NO, I want using this model https://huggingface.co/Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic for text classification for my own data!

Comment: Why do you need to add a dense layer ? Why aren't you using the transformer library for the [classification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/output.html) ?

Comment: How can i use it!?

Comment: I'm a beginner in transformer! tell me If you any helps

Comment: From the code you shared it seem like you are using `keras` with the `transformer` library but they aren't readily compatible. Is your goal to take a sentence and to classify it using `Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic` ? Why did you use keras in the code you shared ?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to classify using Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic.

Comment: Why I'm using Keras? I think because I've used it before, Just!
what other options are easiest to work with with a model like this?

Answer (score 0):

The models from huggingfaces can be used out of the box using the `transformers` library. They can be used with different backends (tensorflow, pytorch).

Using huggingface's transformers with keras is shown [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_extraction_with_bert/#preprocess-the-data) (in the "create_model" function).

Generally speaking you can load a huggingface's transformer using the example code in the [model card](https://huggingface.co/Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic) (the "use in transformers" button):

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Hate-speech-CNERG/dehatebert-mono-arabic")
```

Then to proceed to inference [the doc](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/output.html) shows a way to get the output from a loaded transformer model:

```py
inputs = tokenizer("صباح الخير", return_tensors="pt")
# We're not interested in labels here just the model's inference
# labels = torch.tensor([1]).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
outputs = model(**inputs) #, labels=labels)

# The model returns logits but we want a probability so we use the softmax function
probs = pytorch.softmax(outputs['logits'], 1)
```