# AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'size with hugging-face bert.AutoModel model with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am working on tensorflow 2 and I used Hugface's pre-trained BERT with Tensorflow 2 to do a text classification with it, here I want to create neural network with it:
from tensorflow.keras import layers

```
from transformers import AutoModel

encoder = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

## create neural network input

input_ids = layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)

token_type_ids = layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)

attention_mask = layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)

embedding = encoder(

input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask

)[0]
```

got the error: AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068268/using-pre-trained-transformer-with-keras) answer your query?

Answer (score 4):

Try using

`from transformers import AutoTokenizer,TFAutoModel`

Instead of AutoModel, try using TFAutoModel.

Comment: I was using BertModel, changed it to TFBertModel, and the issue went off, could you please explain, what is the difference?

Comment: BertModel use PyTorch and TFBertModel use TensorFlow.